# How to check if an arbitrary number of matlab.unittest.constraints is satisfied by a cell array?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array of matlab.unittest.constraints and a cell array of values. I'd like to see if the values match the constraints (respectively). Of course, I can just use a for cycle, something like the following code:

```
satisfied = zeros(1,argLength);
for i=1:argLength
    satisfied(i) = satisfiedBy(cons{i}, val{i});
end;
answer = all(satisfied);
```

but knowing MATLAB, there must be a way to condense all that into a single line, I just don't know it. I compare the lengths of the arrays beforehand and return false if they're not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible CELLFUN statement:

```
satisfied = cellfun(@satisfiedBy, cons, val);
```

Make sure `satisfiedBy` returns only single numeric/logical value.

Comment: @VPeric If you're looking for speed, a for loop is likely to be faster because of JIT acceleration.

Comment: @EitanT, I think simple cellfun/arrayfun statement sometimes give a little increase in speed. Especially when `UniformOutput` is set to `true`. But I'd test it in each case.

Comment: I disagree about the little increases in speed, JIT is superfast in recent releases in MATLAB. I do agree that one should test anyway. In any case, +1 :)

Comment: @EitanT Speed is not crucial (I doubt there will ever be more than 10 elements), I'm trying to optimize for readibility and this one-liner looks better to me than my code above. I'll actually go ahead and accept this.